# Pointer (trick): Memory Reference

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory-management

A trick question about C pointer. Read code snippet below  and try explain why the list value changed (this question was based on [this](http://jeffreystedfast.blogspot.com/2010/01/weird-bugs-due-to-gcc-44-and-strict.html) code):

*tail* has the memory address of *list*.

How is possible *list* be changed below?

```
typedef struct _node {
   struct _node *next;
   int value;
}Node;


 int main(){
   Node *list, *node, *tail;
   int i = 100;

   list = NULL;
   printf("\nFirst . LIST value = %d", list);

  tail =(Node *) &list;
  node = malloc (sizeof (Node));
  node->next = NULL;
  node->value = i;

  //tail in this point contains the memory address of list
  tail->next = node;
  printf("\nFinally. LIST value = %d", list);
  printf("\nLIST->value = %d", (list->value));

return 0;
```

}

---- Output

> > First . List value = 0

why this values ??? im not expecting this ...

> > Finally . LIST value = 16909060
> >
> > LIST->value = 100

Comment: what's `i`? where is it declared/defined?

Comment: The code above has several errors that lead to unexpected results

Comment: using a cast is usually a sine that something funny is going on. In normal conditions ou should not need to cast objects to different types. When casting you are in effect telling the compiler you know better than it does and therefore turning off its ability to generate errors because of incompatible types. Usually the compiler actually knows best (don't turn the compiler errors off unless you really need to (ie don't cast unless you really need to)).

Comment: Where's Node???? That code won't even work.... please post the full code in its entirety...there's nothing clever by posting a partial portion of code...

Comment: @jab - I put the code complete now ! stdio.h and stdlib to compile ! Copy and paste and compile ! it works !

Comment: @tommieb75 - Now the code is complete ! Try it now

Comment: @klez - The code is complete now. Try compile and run !

Comment: @CHAPa: There is nothing inherently clever about the code - that is a linked list data structure....btw you should not be using the %d format specifier for a pointer variable....

Comment: @CHAPa As others have said, nothing clever in this. By the way, since you tag C++ for your question. The correct way of doing casts in C++ is using static_cast<>() and dynamic_cast<>(). They are much more safe, and compilation would have warn you about incoherence in your cast ( for the static_cast), and with dynamic cast, the pointer returned would have been NULL since type information are checked at run-time. So as to say, this code is not clever, it is really dirty.

Comment: @tommieb75 - Pay attention .  im changing the value of list using this statement ( tail->next = node; ) The commom way is using pointer to pointer ! pay attention

Comment: @Chapa: you're missing it completely - look at the line above where you've assigned the tail's address - 'tail =(Node *) &list;' - you should be paying attention to not to be using %d format specifiers and understanding a linked list data structure.....

Comment: @tommieb75 - try to debug by hand and see what is happen ! tail contains the list address, list address has NULL as content. (tail)->next == null->next

Comment: @Chapa, it sounds like you are really proud to get something working that is terribly ugly.  Although it works, the code will break sooner or later.  e.g. try printing tail->value, it will be completely nonsense.

Comment: @tommieb75 -  lets try ... list= null ; tail =(Node *) &list; tail->next = node

Comment: @Patrick - im not using this code, im trying understand what happens to work. Should not work !

Comment: @Chapa: so what? both tail and list have the same pointer address to where the pointer is pointing to... and you assigned a malloc'd node to *both* tail and list....and it is dirty code...

Comment: @tommieb75 no man. tail points to list. list has NULL as content

Comment: I give up... two of the rites of passages to C-Guru-dom is 1) study and learn pointers/addresses which cannot be done overnight and 2) to learn not to mess with filthy code that emits undefined behaviour.... and to learn from that... there's thousands of postings of such 'clever' code that should be avoided at all cost!

Comment: @tommieb75 - please, read the patrick comments. you will understand. "It works because of 'stupid luck'. The next member is at offset zero, so setting tail->next to a value is identical to setting the value of the memory where tail is pointing to. But since tail points to list, your are changing the value of list. Try printing tail->value and you will get nonsense" quoted by patrick

Comment: @tommieb75 - should be Trick code ! Try to understand. its funny - its is related with strict aliasing and optimizations

Comment: @tommieb75 - Try to be more polite dude. Its a trick question. take it easy ! Patrick answered correctly !

Comment: @tommieb75 and all - the above code, its not mine, i just want to understand why - source code from : http://jeffreystedfast.blogspot.com/2010/01/weird-bugs-due-to-gcc-44-and-strict.html

Comment: @CHAPa: Ok! Fair enough, **but** I felt after reading that link, you *should* have stated that from the beginning instead of creating endless comments flying around here and editing the question to take that into account far too late.. take that on board and cite the source of where the code comes from originally and not make out giving the impression that you wrote the code, which I have stated earlier and even Scott mentioned about format specifier, it is dirty code. As for the linky, that code is only on the gcc compiler *specifically*, v4.4 series of gcc is indeed buggy & temperamental.

Comment: @CHAPa: explain why your question got downvoted...? Next time... please cite references instead of blindingly copying code and paste it into a subject matter for "discussions" when it has already been mentioned elsewhere....especially on that linky which I appreciate you posting it, albeit too late...

Comment: @tommieb75 - Ok, my fault. Sorry !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's look at what happens to the memory in your program. You start with 3 local variables, all of type `Node*`. At the moment they all point to garbage, as they have been declared but not initialised.

An ascii art diagram of the memory might be (The layout is implementation dependant)

```
      list   node   tail
  --------------------------
... | 0xFE | 0x34 | 0xA3 | ...
  --------------------------
```

You then set list to `NULL`, and `tail` to the address of node (casting away its type, a bad idea), giving you

```
      list   node   tail
  --------------------------
... | NULL | 0xFE | &list | ...
  --------------------------
        ^             |
        +-------------+
```

You then malloc a new `Node`, setting list to its address.

```
      list    node   tail          next  value
  ---------------------------  ------------------
... | NULL | &next | &list | ... | NULL | 100 | ...
  ---------------------------  ------------------
        ^      |       |             ^
        |      +---------------------+
        +--------------+
```

You next try to set `tail->next` to node. You've said that you know `tail` points to a `Node` when you did the typecast, so the compiler believes you. The `Node` tail points to starts at `list`'s address, like so

```
     tail                                list
     next    value                       next   value
  ----------------------------------  ------------------
... | NULL | &list->next | &list | ... | NULL | 100 | ...
  ----------------------------------  ------------------
```

You then set `tail->next` to `node`, making both `list` and `node` point to the `list` structure.

```
      list    node   tail          next  value
   ---------------------------  ------------------
... | &next | &next | &list | ... | NULL | 100 | ...
   ---------------------------  ------------------
       | ^     |       |             ^
       | |     +---------------------|
       | +-------------+             |
       +-----------------------------+
```

You've printed `list` as a signed integer ("%d"). This is a bad idea - if you are using a 64 bit machine and have other arguments in the printf statement they may be clobbered, use the pointer format ("%p") instead. `list->value` is the same as `node->value`, so it's still going to be `100`.

Pointers become easier if you think about how they actually are represented in the machine - as an index to a huge array which holds all of your data (modulo pointer sizes, virtual memory etc.).

Next time it might be easier just to use `list = node`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason tail has memory address of list is in this line

```
tail =(Node *) &list;
```

which means, assign the **address** of the *pointer* pointed to by `list` to the pointer variable `tail`.

And since `tail` and `list` both point to the same address, that is the basics of setting up the linked-list data structure.

**Edit:**
<strike>Speaking of which, there is **NO** reference to `Node` as you have a *struct* **_node** declared...</strike> Amended this to take into account of the OP's code posting that left out `Node`....

Answer (score 2):

The following line is wrong:

```
tail =(Node *) &list;
```

You take the address of the variable list, which is actually of type `Node **`.
Then you cast it to a `Node *`.  Although you can do this in C/C++, this is probably not want you intended.

To get the wanted behavior, tail should be of type `Node **`.  So no casting is needed anymore, and at the end, you need to write `(*tail)->next = node`.

Comment: Not at all.Try compile and execute ! this code run correctly ! This is the clever question ;)

Comment: @CHAPa, please define "correctly" - your definition seems to differ from that of others...

Comment: It works because of 'stupid luck'.  The next member is at offset zero, so setting tail->next to a value is identical to setting the value of the memory where tail is pointing to.  But since tail points to list, your are changing the value of list.  Try printing tail->value and you will get nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
tail =(Node *) &list;
```

assigns *the address of* `list` to `tail`. Since `&list` is a `Node **`, the compiler doesn't like this assignment by default, so you add an explicit cast to silence it. Then

```
tail->next = node;
```

changes a member value in the struct supposedly pointed to by `tail` (at least the compiler believes it is a struct, since you explicitly told it so). Since `next` is the first member of the struct, its address is most likely the same as that of the struct itself. And since `tail` points to the address of `list`, in effect this assignment changes the value of `list`, which is a pointer to a `_node`. That is, it makes `list` point to `node`.

<strike>What you probably want is</strike>

```
Node** tail;
...
tail = &list;
...
(*tail)->next = node;
```

That is, declare `tail` as a pointer to pointer to `_node`, and add the extra indirection (`*`) when assigning a value through it.

Comment: yeah, i know that, but this question is to show you that this trick works. Why it works is the question, understand ? The correct, surely, would be pointer to pointer ! Perfectly !

Comment: why did you add the extra level of indirection, that is changing the OP's original code completely... the extra level of indirection is useful if that was a function parameter .... in which the function can modify the list directly

Comment: @CHAPa, I think I gave an explanation to why it works, but now I added some more details just to (hopefully) make it clearer. @tommie, sorry for incorrectly "fixing" the code - I still believe though that the original solution is far from safe, and it is not a good idea to do such casts, only in experimental code.

Comment: @tommie, indeed not - check carefully that I was referring to `&list` :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in setting

```
tail = (Node*) &list
```

Thus list is a Node*, tail is a Node** , which is cast to Node*. Now here

```
tail->next == (*tail)+0 == (*&list)+0
```

thus

`tail->next == list`

Thus changing tail->next is the same as changing list.

Answer (score 2):

By assigning the *address* of `list` to `tail`, you cause `list` and `tail->next` to refer to the same location in memory; when you assign to one, you clobber the other.

Let's start by looking at a hypothetical memory map of `node` after allocation and assignments (assuming 4 byte pointers and ints):

```
Object     Address      0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
------     -------      ----  ----  ----  ----
node       0x08000004   0x10  0x00  0x00  0x00  // points to address 0x10000000
...
node.next  0x10000000   0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  // points to NULL
node.value 0x10000004   0x00  0x00  0x00  0x64  // value = 100 decimal
```

When you write `node->next = NULL`, you're assigning NULL to memory location 0x10000000.  IOW, the value of `node` corresponds to the address where `node->next` will be found.

Now let's look at a hypothetical layout of `list`, `node`, and `tail` after you've assigned `list` and `tail`

```
Object     Address      0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
------     -------      ----  ----  ----  ----
list       0x08000000   0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  // after list = NULL
node       0x08000004   0x10  0x00  0x00  0x00  // after node = malloc(sizeof *node);
tail       0x08000008   0x08  0x00  0x00  0x00  // after tail = (Node*) &list;
```

So now here's the memory map of `tail` after you've assigned `tail->next`:

```
Object     Address      0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
------     -------      ----  ----  ----  ----
tail       0x08000008   0x08  0x00  0x00  0x00  // points to address 0x80000000,
...                                             // which is where list lives
tail.next  0x08000000   0x08  0x00  0x00  0x04  // points to node
tail.value 0x08000004   0x10  0x00  0x00  0x00  // value = some big number
```

Presto: `list` now contains the address of `node`.

Please for the love of God never do this in production code.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this line...

```
tail =(Node *) &list;
```

assigning to tail the address of the pointer to list, not the address of list?

Answer (score 0):

If memory is changing unexpectedly the quickest way to track down the issue is to configure a breakpoint conditional on the memory change, including the size of the memory block of interest - 4 in this case, assuming it's a 32-bit platform pointer.  In Windows (Visual Studio IDE or Windbg) this is easy to do - I have no info on other systems.

Usually you will find what's causing the issue very quickly this way.